# Редирект с wp-login рабочей версии сайта на админку dev. версии сайта на Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, url, redirect

Нужно реализовать редирект при попытке входа в админ-панель Wordpress на рабочей версии сайта, чтобы при переходе на **example.com/wp-admin/** происходило перенаправление на **dev.example.com/wp-admin/**

Логика в том, что все работы с сайтом происходят на **dev.example.com** и периодически все изменения деплоятся на **example.com** и соответственно каждый деплой происходит обновление всех файлов на последнем

Хочется внедрить данное решение, во избежание работы с сайтом на оригинальной версии, потому что при деплое с dev версии перезаписываются все внесенные изменения на оригинале

Также нюансы:

- при деплое скрипт заменяет все ссылки вида **dev.example.com** на **example.com**, поэтому желательно не использовать в функции полноценный url
- при переходе на **dev.example.com/wp-admin/** как обычно должна открываться форма входа в админ-панель (возможно, функция в php должна иметь проверку на наличие поддомена dev. / исключение для поддомена dev.)
- была попытка реализовать следующую функцию в functions.php:

```
function custom_login(){
 global $pagenow;
 if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow && !is_user_logged_in()) {
  wp_redirect('dev.example.com/wp-admin/');
  exit();
 }
}
```

но нюанс в том, что функция работает для example.com/wp-admin/, но при этом, очевидно, получаем зацикленный редирект на dev.example.com/wp-admin/

- мы не можем сделать разные функции на двух версиях сайта, так как периодически происходит деплой и файлы на последнем перезаписываются, функция должна быть универсальна и корректно работать как на dev. так и на оригинале

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Бред какой-то... Если логинится на подакшене не нужно (что уже само по себе бред) - ну закрой доступ сервером и ходи только на дев.

Comment: логиниться на продакшне нужно определенным лицам, поэтому задаю вопрос, как здесь можно продумать логику, чтобы людей, которые должны логиниться только на dev для работы с сайтом, и которые могут допустить ошибку и залогиниться на продакшене, забыв про дев, админка перебрасывала на дев версию. может быть можно сделать какую-то специальную приписку к url для логина на продакшн

Comment: Теперь уже "можно определенным лицам". В вопросе об этом ни слова, а это меняет всё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На продакшен сервере удалите админов, которым доступ туда запрещен или лишите их роли админов.

Если же у вас одна база данных на dev и prod, то на уровне вебсервера для папки wp-admin на prod установите дополнительно http авторизацию. В nginx это делается [так](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html). Apache [так](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html).